# How to use the max number for every line in awk?

Tags: linux, awk

Here is a simple awk script **max1.awk** to get the max length of all lines.

```
#! /usr/bin/awk 
BEGIN {max =0 }
{
    if (length($0) > max) { max = length($0)}
}
END {print max}
```

It can get max length with some test file.

```
awk -f max1.awk  test_file
```

Now to  move all awk script into BEGIN block as below  **max2.awk**.

```
#! /usr/bin/awk 
BEGIN {max =0;
    if (length($0) > max) { max = length($0)};
    print max}
```

Why can't print max length on test_file with **awk -f max2.awk  test_file**?
How can i use the max number for every line ?

Comment: What don't you like about `max1.awk`? What's your real goal here? As explained by Kent, the `BEGIN` block is executed before any lines are read from the file (`$0` is the empty string in that case). Except for the fact that the `BEGIN` block isn't necessary (because the initial value of `max` already defaults to `0`), `max1.awk` is perfectly correct.

Comment: also, there's already a command to do it... `wc -L < test_file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BEGIN` block will be processed before awk reading lines, if your script has only `BEGIN` block, no line will be loaded, only `BEGIN` blocked was executed by awk.

Thus, your max length calculation was not done.

E.g.

```
kent$  awk 'BEGIN{print length($0)}'<<<"foo"
0 #here we get 0 instead of 3, because default var in awk is "". 
  #If you print NR, it is 0 as well.
```

Comment: How can i use the max number for every line ?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature take it out from the `BEGIN{}`

Answer (score 0):

You can read your file line by line by means of `getline`. If you use it in your `BEGIN` block and repeat as long as it returns 1, you can process the whole input stream. 
Add this line before your `if` statement:

```
while ( getline > 0 )
```

The whole script looks as follows:

```
BEGIN {max =0
    while ( getline > 0 )  
       if (length($0) > max) { max = length($0)}
    print max}
```